# How to replace URL of Image in react native

Tags: react-native, replace

I want to replace  "file:/" to "file://" this.

I want to replace this code

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "lead_tag_number",
      "NAS00001",
    ],
    Array [
      "upload_pan_card_file",
      Object {
        "singleFile": "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAwesomeProject-caa28295-07ae-40d0-8b07-905883f99373/ImagePicker/6853c307-087c-48be-9a23-3ac01db646d4.jpg",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

to this code

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "lead_tag_number",
      "NAS00001",
    ],
    Array [
      "upload_pan_card_file",
      Object {
        "singleFile": "file://data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAwesomeProject-caa28295-07ae-40d0-8b07-905883f99373/ImagePicker/6853c307-087c-48be-9a23-3ac01db646d4.jpg",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

I am getting It in console when I print console.log(data). please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    let filename = "file://data/blablabla.jpg"
    filename = filename.replace('file:/', 'file://');
```

Comment: .replace is undefined

Comment: Can I see how did you use the .replace? I think you are still using the object FormData